# Change “POST” type slug in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

> /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=project

How to change slug of default post in wordpress (from project to projects)

I tried by adding the function below

```
add_filter(
    'pre_post_link',
    function ($permalink, $post) {
        if ($post->post_type !== 'project') {
            return $permalink;
        }

        return '/projects';
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

But it does not work

Comment: do you use any plugin for custom post type?

Comment: No it is coming with theme @Krupal Panchal

Comment: It looks like a custom post type. Please check once more.

Comment: no i am very much sure that is  default post coming with theme @Krupal Panchal

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Comment: If it is in fact the default post type, then the theme is already filtering it to change its name to project from post. So if that is the case then your filter might be running before the themes filter and so it will look like it is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

$args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'projects';

add this code in if condition and **remove return** from if conndition